# Entity Framework 6 with MySQL - UniqueIdentifier issues

Tags: mysql, entity-framework-6, uniqueidentifier

I have migrated my MS SQL Server database to MySQL and everything seems to be fine except the uniqueidentifier columns.

Actually MySQL converts uniqueidentifier to VARCHAR(64) and now when I run my .Net application (which uses Entity Framework 6) I am getting a cast exception as all my code refers to GUID datatype so can someone tell me, Is there anyway I can still use the same code and workaround this issue?

```
public Guid ProjectID { get; set; }
```

If not, I have to change all my GUID related code to string which is going to be really painful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have to use CHAR(36) instead of VARCHAR(64) (which has been generated by MySql Workbench tool at the time of migration) and the Entity Framework automatically treats it as GUID and everything is working fine for me.